# How to shift the phase (185 degrees) of the triangle waveform without a distortion?

Tags: phase-shift

I need to phase shift the input waveform exactly 185 degrees. Unfortunately, I can't find a good/simple way to do it. Thanks. [image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117185/discussion-on-question-by-jerzy-przezdziecki-how-to-shift-the-phase-185-degrees).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a 185° shift (which is an inversion + 5° shift) is hard, because if you actually need your circuit to work 20 Hz to 20 kHz, these 5° can mean delaying by 1/72 of 50 µs or up to 1/72 of 50 ms – you need some circuit to adjust the delay according to your frequency. In the end, you'd build something like a PLL.

In all honesty, get a microcontroller that has a PWM unit that can generate two complementary outputs and has a *dead time* functionality – it's exactly what you need. That solves the problem you're having before having it.

Or use a microcontroller with two PWM units (that's very standard – 1€ microcontrollers have that) and start one with an offset that gives you the shift you need.

However, assuming your comment:

> I do need any solution to end up with phase-shifted waveform. So inverting the input by 180 + fixed time delay would do the trick I guess. So advice about how to delay it would be great.

Since you say you actually *don't* need the fixed 5° but a fixed delay works, this becomes relatively easy:

1. invert your signal. That's 180°, for every frequency!
2. Add a fixed delay.

That fixed delay can be built using a sample-and-hold circuit (better: two in series). You end up with a bucket-brigade device. The cheap and lazy way of solving this is using a microcontroller with built-in ADC and a DAC (or filtered PWM, which is a DAC...) to delay. Again, as you can see, the solution that you *generate* two triangular waves to begin with becomes more and more tempting.

Note that you'd need to be pretty fast about sampling your input if you need to support a triangle wave of 20 kHz – that has frequency components easily above 200 kHz that you'll need to retain to keep the thing nice and sharp – and thus will need a lot of "memory" (in shapes of charge buckets or actual RAM in a microcontroller). Easier would be to first differentiate the input signal using an opamp to convert the triangle wave to a square wave, and then delay that, and then integrate the result again. As you can see, now we're getting *really* close to how a triangle wave is originally constructed.